# PHP Redierct with if, if else and else

Tags: php

Hello I have a question about php.

I want to create a special redirect script but its not working. I want to check if the 'keyword' is in the list. If in the list than redirect with 'header location' If not redirect to a searchmachine with the value you get from $_get.

```
<?php
$q=$_get['q']
if ($q = tw) {
header('Location: http://twitter.com');
exit;
} else if ($q = fb) {
header('Location: http://fb.com');
exit;
} else {
header('Location: https://searchit.com/search?q='$q'+ ');
}
?>
```

I have a list with 10 keyword now like

```
tw twitter.com
fb facebook.com
gg google.com
```

etc. all in a text list.

Comment: where is the list? give an example of the list.

Comment: Where you are defining the `$q`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the $q= but even with this code its still not working. I just see a empty page.

Comment: surely you are generating Warning/Error./.. Try to debug with "echo" not redirect. And where the 'tw' or 'fb' defined?

Comment: turn on error reporting with `error_reporting(-1);` as the 1st line of your script. then use `'` or `"` around strings. then learn the difference between `=`, `==`, `===`. you should get an `undefined constant` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your code: `header('Location: https://searchit.com/search?q='$q'+ ');` seem to be the issue with the blank pange, also called "white page of death" :)

Try `header('Location: https://searchit.com/search?q=' . $q);`

---

You also forgot a semicolon after: `$q=$_get['q']`

---

You could also try this setup:

```
switch($_GET['q'])
{
  case 'tw':
    header('Location: http://twitter.com');
    exit;
  case 'fb':
    header('Location: http://fb.com');
    exit;
  default:
    header('Location: https://searchit.com/search?q=' . urlencode($_GET['q']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write like

`$q=$_GET['q'];`

and not `$_get` it would be `$_GET['q']` or you can use `$_REQUEST['q']`

and use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

to see if any error on you page.

Comment: not downvoting. but the code in the question is just a snippet. he may have defined it somewhere else in the script. you can't 100% surely say this.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. I edited the code a bit. But when I update the code to $_GET the page keep empty. Its not redirecting me to another page.

Comment: have you use `$_REQUEST['q'];` ? use `$_REQUEST` and `print_r($_REQUEST);` and you can see what request are you getting.

Comment: and you are not using **semicolon** after `$q=$_GET['q']`